# Parsing an array encoded in JSON through perl

Tags: perl, json

I am using the Following Perl code to parse an array in JSON, using the [`JSON` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON). But the array returned has length 1 and I am not able to iterate over it properly. So the problem is I am not able to use the array returned.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $json_text = '[ {"name" : "abc", "text" : "text1"}, {"name" : "xyz", "text" : "text2"} ]';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper::Names;

my @decoded_json = decode_json($json_text);
print Dumper(@decoded_json), length(@decoded_json), "\n";
```

The output comes :

```
$VAR1 = [
     {
        'text' => 'text1',
        'name' => 'abc'
      },
      {
        'text' => 'text2',
        'name' => 'xyz'
      }
    ];
1
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`decode_json` function](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-2.22/lib/JSON.pm#decode_json) returns an arrayref, not a list.  You must dereference it to get the list:

```
my @decoded_json = @{decode_json($json_text)};
```

You may want to read [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Comment: Dereferencing helps a bit. Now I am able to iterate over the array returned. But still I get length of the array = 1

Comment: My bad. Was using length(@decoded_json) to get length of the array!!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding JSON, you may want to make sure you install the [`JSON::XS` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) as it is faster and more stable than the pure Perl implementation included with the [`JSON` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON). The `JSON` module will use `JSON::XS` automatically when it is available.