# loop over JSON using Perl

Tags: json, perl

I'm a newbie to Perl and want to loop over this JSON data and just print it out to the screen.

How can I do that?

```
$arr = '[{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q3","DataType":"Other 3","Environment":"STEVE","Amount":125},{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q4","DataType":"Other 2","Environment":"MIKE","Amount":500}]';
```

Comment: If you want it in Perl, then why the JavaScript tag?

Comment: In Computer Science we're always looking for a more general solution to a problem, which often involves looking at a problem from a more general perspective.  The specific problem you have is not knowing how to parse JSON, and the specific solution is provided in the answer you accepted.  But the more general problem is not knowing where to find Perl tools.  The more general solution is to become familiar with a CPAN search site, such as https://metacpan.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/) or [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON-XS) to decode the JSON into a Perl structure.

Simple example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;

my $json = '[{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q3","DataType":"Other 3","Environment":"STEVE","Amount":125},{"Year":"2012","Quarter":"Q4","DataType":"Other 2","Environment":"MIKE","Amount":500}]';

my $arrayref = decode_json $json;

foreach my $item( @$arrayref ) { 
    # fields are in $item->{Year}, $item->{Quarter}, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You have an array of hashes.

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $records = decode_json($json_text);
for my $record (@$records) {
   for my $key (keys(%$record)) {
      my $val = $record->{$key};
      say "$key: $val";
    }
}
```

[JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package on CPAN that should do the trick, [JSON.pm](http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON)

Once you parse it, you can treat it like any other Perl reference.

**Example**

```
$perl_scalar = $json->decode($json_text)
```

---

**Documentation**

> The opposite of encode: expects a JSON text and tries to parse it,
>   returning the resulting simple scalar or reference. Croaks on error.
>
> JSON numbers and strings become simple Perl scalars. **JSON arrays become Perl arrayrefs** and JSON objects become Perl hashrefs. true
>   becomes 1 (JSON::true), false becomes 0 (JSON::false) and null becomes
>   undef.`

Similar stack overflow question:
[Parsing an array encoded in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695105/parsing-an-array-encoded-in-json-through-perl)